# Javascript calander to pick contents on a particular date

Tags: 7

Is there any module available in drupal which can be used to pick a date and afterwards contents from a particular content type can be displayed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this sort of functionality with the very powerful [FullCalendar](http://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) module. It provides extensions to Views enabling you to build complex calendars displaying content, users, and basically anything else a View can display.